# SQL datediff time calculation

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have these fields in my T-SQL database - `startTime` and `endTime` and `processTime`.
The process time is the amount of time from start to end time.
So, one startTime example is `22:50:59` and its endTime is `23:14:23`.
Process time would be .39  (The current code):

```
SELECT convert( decimal(18,0), totalItems 
        /(datediff(ss,sessionStartTime,sessionEndTime)/60.00/60.00) ) 
  AS processTime
```

This seems to be working for the most part, but it doesn't work when the startTime and endTime span across a day - for example, a startTime is 23:17:27 and an endTime of 00:31:23.

In other words, they started at 10:17 p.m., and finished at about 12:31 a.m. the following morning, but SQL isn't seeing this, because the processTime is displaying as a negative number (-22.77)...
**How do I convert these negative times into positive times?**

I do have separate date fields - a `startDate`, and an `endDate`.

Comment: @kuru kuru pa, are you sure that the OP is talking about T-SQL or are you just assuming it? I'm asking because he posted the question with the "sql" tag only.

Comment: @Christian -- an assumption, but safe enough.  OP's only ever asked about SQL-Server in previous questions, and MS Access is the only other non-TSQL db with datediff() (unless you can find some really obscure dialect that uses it).

Comment: @kuru kuru pa: ok, fair enough. I was thinking about MySQL because I was quite sure that it has datediff() as well, but I just looked it up again and found out that MySQL's datediff() can only return the difference in days. So the OP's code example can't be MySQL and you're probably right.

Comment: @Christian -- good point on the mySQL version, though as you point out, the parms are different.  I still won't be surprised if the OP to come back and says 'no -- it's actually XYZ-SQL'...  I'd deserve it :-P

Comment: In case it has escaped some people's notice - the author has separate date and time fields.  This appears to be causing the bulk of the issue.  For the OP - unless there's some actual reason _why_ they should be separated, always store date and time together as a timestamp (with the timezone, if necessary!).  This will save you from all sorts of headaches (like this...) in the future.  Also, get the relevant relevant unit out of `datediff` - don't convert it yourself.

Comment: @X-Zero: no, it didn't escape our notice - we simply didn't know it at the time. The OP added this information to the question after our answers were already written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're including dates...(?)

Here is a sample I ran -- seems to work as expected:

```
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime

set @start = '2011-09-06 23:17:27'
set @end = '2011-09-07 00:31:23'

select 
    datediff(second,@start,@end) as seconds, 
    datediff(minute,@start,@end) as minutes,
    datediff(hour,@start,@end) as hours,
    datediff(day,@start,@end) as days,
    datediff(month,@start,@end) as months,
    datediff(year,@start,@end) as years
```

Here's the results:

```
seconds     minutes     hours       days        months      years
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
4436        74          1           1           0           0

(1 row(s) affected)
```

One thing you might do is re-check the scope of your decimal conversion.  E.g.: this produces a different results, depending on where you put the parens before the division:

```
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime

set @start = '2011-09-06 23:17:27'
set @end = '2011-09-07 00:31:23'

select convert(decimal(18,0), (datediff(ss,@start,@end)))/60.00/60.00 as NEW_processTime,
       convert(decimal(18,0), (datediff(ss,@start,@end)/60.00/60.00)) as ORIGINAL_processTime
```

Here are the results of that:

```
NEW_processTime                         ORIGINAL_processTime
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1.23222221666                           1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: lesson learned.  i added a new field to my table with concatenated corresponding dates and timestamp.  now this solution works well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, what database engine are we talking about? MS SQL Server? MySQL? Something else?

I mostly work with MS SQL Server and I don't know the `datediff` implementations of other database engines, but your problem probably occurs because your `startTime` and `endTime` fields contain only time information, but no date:

If you give `datediff` only `23:17:27` and `00:31:23`, how should it "decide"/"know" whether you mean the same day?
But if you would set `startTime` to `2011-09-06 23:17:27` and `endTime` to `2011-09-07 00:31:23`, it would work because `datediff` would definitely know that `endTime` is not at the same day as `startTime`.

Comment: the TSQL tag means it could be MS SQL or Sybase and they're probably equivalent anyway

Comment: Maybe...but at the time when I posted my answer, the "tsql" tag wasn't there yet, only "sql" and nothing else. Look at the edit history of the question!

Comment: And I'm not even sure that the OP was actually asking about T-SQL...see my comment on the question

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're working in MS SQL and for some reason you're stripping out the date component so the date is always the same. You can fix this by testing the date and if the end time is less then the start time add a day to the end time.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 0), totalitems / 
     ( CASE 
             WHEN sessionendtime < sessionstarttime THEN Datediff(ss, sessionstarttime, Dateadd(dd, 1, 
       sessionendtime )) 
            ELSE Datediff(ss, sessionstarttime, sessionendtime ) 
       END)/ 
       60.00/60.00)
```

This solution is problematic if the end time is greater than 24 hours after the start time